# string.Replace() Function

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to replace a sub-string in the errorString. i am using this code,which is not making any changes to errorString. am i following a wrong method?

```
 string errorstring = "<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Name:{StudentName}</p>";
 errorstring.Replace("{StudentName}", "MyName");
```

i want to replace {StudentName} in errorString with "MyName"

Comment: Strings are immutable and you're just creating new string instance, use `errorstring = errorstring.Replace("{StudentName}", "MyName");` instead.

Comment: Thank you @Tetsuya .it Worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a new instance of that string:

```
string errorstring = "<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Name:{StudentName}</p>";
errorstring = errorstring.Replace("{StudentName}", "MyName");
```

That should work if you don't use StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps.

Step :- 1

```
 string errorstring = "<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Name:{StudentName}</p>";
    errorstring = errorstring.Replace("{StudentName}", "MyName");
```

Step :- 2

```
@Html.Raw(errorstring)
```